# Linking table of data without primary key to layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I have a parcel layer with the following attributes :

```
OBJECTID    
PARCELNO
PARCELNOOL
MAHDARID
MAHDARNO    
MAHDARDATE  
PARCELNAME  
PLANID
PLANNO
PLANBLOCKI
SUBMUNICIP
DISTRICT
LANDMARKID
PARCELSUBT
LANDUSEAGR
LANDUSEADE
SHAPE
```

And I'm trying to link it (Relationship) with table of data (Transactions) that have these attributes :

totalPrice, area , planNo,parcelNo

I try to link the table with planNo and parcelNo in parcel layer but the problem they can be duplicated.

I am thinking additionally to the planNo and parcelNo to use the `Area` in transactions table with `SHAPE` from parcel layer.

Is it possible to get the area from the shape?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Get the area from the shape field of your layer and join it to your table, or get the area field from the table and join it to the layer?

Comment: @gisge The first one , getting the area from the shape and join it to the table

Comment: What is the format of your table?

Comment: @Gisge I'm not sure what you mean but the table in geoDatabase